How to update value of CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl programmatically in Flutter
CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl doesn't provide a way to update the value programmatically. The only workaround is to update a key, e.g., ValueKey, but doing so would disable the sliding transition, making it less ideal.
CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    thumbColor: ColorAssets.green,
    groupValue: selected,
    onValueChanged: (value) {
     
    },
    children: widget.children.map(
      (key, value) => MapEntry(
        key,
         Container(
            height: constraints.maxHeight,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
            child: Text(
              value,
            ),
          )
      ),
    ),
  )


You can update CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl without messing with keys by using setState to update the variable you're passing to the groupValue parameter.
setState(() => selected = /* put your new value here */);

Here's an example with code:

and here's the code. Scroll to the bottom for the relevant portion where you update the segmented control programatically.
// SCROLL TO THE BOTTOM FOR THE RELEVANT PORTION

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum Sky { midnight, viridian, cerulean }

Map<Sky, Color> skyColors = <Sky, Color>{
  Sky.midnight: const Color(0xff191970),
  Sky.viridian: const Color(0xff40826d),
  Sky.cerulean: const Color(0xff007ba7),
};

void main() => runApp(const SegmentedControlApp());

class SegmentedControlApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SegmentedControlApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const CupertinoApp(
      theme: CupertinoThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light),
      home: SegmentedControlExample(),
    );
  }
}

class SegmentedControlExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const SegmentedControlExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<SegmentedControlExample> createState() =>
      _SegmentedControlExampleState();
}

class _SegmentedControlExampleState extends State<SegmentedControlExample> {
  Sky _selectedSegment = Sky.midnight;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      backgroundColor: skyColors[_selectedSegment],
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        // This Cupertino segmented control has the enum "Sky" as the type.
        middle: CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl<Sky>(
          backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey2,
          thumbColor: skyColors[_selectedSegment]!,
          // This represents the currently selected segmented control.
          groupValue: _selectedSegment,
          // Callback that sets the selected segmented control.
          onValueChanged: (Sky? value) {
            if (value != null) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedSegment = value;
              });
            }
          },
          children: const <Sky, Widget>{
            Sky.midnight: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Text(
                'Midnight',
                style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.white),
              ),
            ),
            Sky.viridian: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Text(
                'Viridian',
                style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.white),
              ),
            ),
            Sky.cerulean: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Text(
                'Cerulean',
                style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.white),
              ),
            ),
          },
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Selected Segment: ${_selectedSegment.name}',
              style: const TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.white),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            ElevatedButton(
              // Update the segmented control programatically here!
              onPressed: () => setState(() => _selectedSegment = Sky.cerulean),
              child: Text('Update Programatically to Cerulean'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Oh! I was expecting "selectedValue" field from parent stateful widget would change value of this cupertino widget, upon calling the "setState"... My bad!
Thank you so much for pointing out!!

Here is the Snippet to achieve toggling CupertinoSegmentedControl programmatically.
where sliderkey is given to CupertinoSegmentedControl widget.
 void toggle(int index) {
  final x = (sliderKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).size.width;
  (sliderKey.currentState as dynamic)?.onTapUp(TapUpDetails(
      kind: PointerDeviceKind.touch,
      localPosition: Offset(index * (x / (widget.children.length)), (widget.children.length + 1))));
}

